# C++ simple matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

can someone fix my code?
this is the result that should be showed when i input number 5 in c++

```
1
2  6  
3  7  10  
4  8  11  13  
5  9  12  14  15
```

my result:

```
1
2  6  
3  7  10  
4  8  11  14  
5  9  12  15  18
```

my code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    cout<<"insert number"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    { 
        int y=1;
        int g=1;
        cout<<i<<"     ";
        for (j=1;j<=i-1;j++)
        {
            int x=n;
            int b=i;
            x--;
            g--;
            cout<<(x*y)+b+g<<"      ";
            y++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    getch ();
}
```

what did i do wrong?
sorry if my code messy i'm a c++ new learner.

Comment: Wat? What are you trying to do? Could you please clarify?

Comment: sorry because my english is horrible , i've already edit it.

Comment: The problem is not your English, but that you didn't state your goal @Atika. However, at least two users (including me) understood what you want and provided an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n , i ,j, sum;
    cout << "masukkan bilanga" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << "     ";
        sum = i + 1;
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            sum += n - 1 - j;
            cout << sum << "     ";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

where the key point is that you want to print all the numbers, starting from 1, in a column-major manner, until a triangular *n* x *n* matrix is created.

Driven from the output, one can easily see that every element of the next column is what the current element is, plus `n - 1`, and that factor decreases by one as we advance to the right part of the matrix.

Comment: thank you so much , this is exactly what i want . ;;;

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, hope this is what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printMatrix(int number);

void main()
{
  int number = 1;
  std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
  std::cin >> number;
  printMatrix(number);
}

void printMatrix(int number) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        std::cout << i << "  ";
        int n = i;
        for(int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            n += number - j;
            std::cout << n << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```